# how to insert model object value using HQL insert statement

Tags: hibernate, insert, hql

i have  HQL statement ...

```
insert into Item(itemName, itemId) select i.itemName,i.itemId from Item i where i.itemId=?,i.itemName=?
```

using this i am tring to insert my model object value but didn't get the result....
Help would BE appreciated..

here is full code...

```
public String Additem( Item i) {
     Session session=HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
     Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
     System.out.println(i.getItemId());
      insert into Item(itemName, itemId) select i.itemName,i.itemId from Item i where i.itemId=?,i.itemName=?;


 Query query= session.createQuery(hq).setString(0,i.getItemId()).setStrig(1,i.getItemName());   
     query.executeUpdate();
    transaction.commit();
    session.flush();
    session.close();            

    return "success";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your query with some changes which is

```
insert into Item(itemName, itemId) select i.itemName,i.itemId from Item i where i.itemId=? and i.itemName=?
```

and the query you posted is

```
insert into Item(itemName, itemId) select i.itemName,i.itemId from Item i where i.itemId=?,i.itemName=?
```

i only replaced `,` with `and` keyword and it worked.

Comment: thanks for the quick response..but HQL insert query is given to insert records into one DB table by selecting from another database table....i found this right now...so this scenario is not possible

Comment: Yes it is what it is. Here in your case it will insert duplicate row with selected tuples set from your existing `Item class table` row satisfying your conditions, so this scenario is also possible because i performed it first and then posted anser here.